# Adjusting the content size of my theme

Tags: theming

I have not messed around with themes much yet, but I would really like to be able to adjust the relative width of different blocks in my Bartik theme. As you can see in the screenshot, my panel is not quite big enough to display both views without overlapping, and there is plenty of extra space on the sides.

[image: screenshot]

How does one change the relative widths assigned to each block?  Also, when I start making changes like this, would it be wise to make my own copy of Bartik and store it elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

This is something you would most likely want to adjust using your style.css file and an inspector program (such as [DOM Inspector for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/)) in the browser.

Another way to do it would be to use a grid-based theme like [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) that lets you choose how many columns wide to make zones and regions. Using [Omega Tools](http://drupal.org/project/omega_tools) you can do that directly in the Appearance admin configuration UI.